# proper type hint for __getitem__()

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

The method `__getitem__()` for a sequence (such as a list) can return a single item, or a sequence of items. For example, given the function decoration below:

```
def __getitem__(self, index) -> Union[Product, Generator[Product, None, None]]:
    return super(Products, self).__getitem__(index)
```

Example usage:

```
i1 = 34
for product in products[i1:]:
    print(product.name)
```

I believe `Union[Product, Generator[Product, None, None]]` to be correct, but PyCharm flags this as improper. Am I misusing the typing library, or is this a PyCharm issue?

Thanks!

Comment: `Generator` is for generators, not for sequences.

Comment: That works, but raises another question - List or Sequence?

From standard docs: 

1. [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) states: "When used as an expression, a slice is a sequence of the same type"
2. [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) states: "List(list, MutableSequence[T])
Generic version of list. Useful for annotating return types. To annotate arguments it is preferred to use abstract collection types such as Mapping, Sequence, or AbstractSet."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct type hint for `__getitem__()` is `Union[Product, Sequence[Product, None, None]]`.

The only place this seems to be documented in the docs is on the [data model page](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) which states: "When used as an expression, a slice is a sequence of the same type". **Note: a sequence like type (such as List) should also work**, see [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List).

Further discussion: I was expecting a generator when using a slice with a sequence while being iterated over because they are more memory efficient. But now it is obvious to me that this would result in constantly having to do: `l_2 = list(l_1[2:])`, which would be annoying.